# .Net SerialPort Readline Vs DataReceived Event Handler

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

In VB.NET, what is the difference between using the SerialPort.ReadLine() method versus using the DataReceived event handler? Currently, I'm using the data received event handler and detecting the line endings. The problem is the data is coming in chunks and not 1 line sentences. If I use SerialPort.ReadLine() method, the data comes in 1 line sentences. Using this method, however, has the NewLine variable to set the line ending character for the port. Is the readline method just handling the buffer for me? Does the data still come in chunks regardless of the method used?

Method 1:

```
While _continue
    Try 
        Dim message As String = _serialPort.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(message)
    Catch generatedExceptionName As TimeoutException
    End Try 
End While
```

Method 2:

```
Public Sub StartListener()
    Try

        _serialport = New SerialPort()
        With _serialport
            .PortName = "COM3"
            .BaudRate = 38400
            .DataBits = 8
            .Parity = Parity.None
            .StopBits = StopBits.One
            .Handshake = Handshake.None
            AddHandler .DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler
        End With
        _serialport.Open()

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Shared buffer As String = ""

Private Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim rcv As String = _serialport.ReadExisting()
        buffer = String.Concat(buffer, rcv)

        Dim x As Integer
        Do
            x = buffer.IndexOf(vbCrLf)
            If x > -1 Then
                Console.WriteLine(buffer.Substring(0, x).Trim())
                buffer = buffer.Remove(0, x + 2)
            End If
        Loop Until x = -1
    Catch ex as Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

I am currently using Method 2, but was thinking about switching to Method 1 because it seems safer and looks prettier you know, but what's the point? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with the .NET SerialPort implementation, you should ***NEVER*** try to read from the serial port using the DataReceived event and any other method. `ReadExisting` and `ReadLine` both use the same underlying MemoryStream. You will run into situations where you are pulling data off the MemoryStream from the ReadLine when the event interrupts causing you to attempt to read data that has already been removed from the stream.

Use one method or the other. Do no use both.

Hans Passant is correct about the `ReadLine` blocking your UI thread. You have two methods around that: use the `DataReceived` event; or place your code that handles the `SerialPort` on a separate thread.

Using the `DataReceived` event is usually preferable as .NET will run that on a worker thread automatically. You lose the freebie of the `ReadLine` though. And you have to manually buffer the input if you need to perform read aheads (to give you something like the ReadLine functionality).

Comment: Currently, we have so much data coming into the stream, that we are unsure as to the reliability of the DataReceived event. We are having problems with message parts getting mixed up with each other. I'm guessing it has something to do with the asynchronous part accessing the same shared variable. The buffer is getting modified, I think, not in the order that the data is coming in. Any suggestions? THANK YOU

Comment: Are you attempting multiple concurrent communications over a single serial port? If so, you will need to have some type of protocol implemented that lets you know what response belongs with what request, an end of response code, and a whole bunch of other things. The SerialPort is not like a USB connection where you can easily have separate and concurrent transfers. If not, it sounds like your flow control hasn't been implemented, possibly you are ignoring it.

Comment: Looking through the code you provided, I don't see any references to flow control at all. At a minimum, you should implement a software flow control. The best solution (if your cable supports it) would be a hardware flow control.

Comment: I went ahead and edited method 2 to show more detail, can I add flow control using .net? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. What kind of flow control you add is going to depend on the cable you have and the device on the remote end. If either the cable or the remote device don't support hardware flow control, you will have to use software flow control. You have one line: `.Handshake = Handshake.None` that says to not use any kind of flow control.

Answer (score 3):

Your ReadLine() call is synchronous and blocks your code, potentially hanging your program.  DataReceived is asynchronous and doesn't.  Which makes it harder to use, there is no free lunch.  But can be important, serial ports can be slow enough to make your entire program unresponsive to user input.  Not usually an issue in a console mode program or when you use a separate thread.

You can call ReadLine() in your DataReceived event handler as well, that's desert.  That can technically cause deadlock, you should use the ReadTimeout property.

But since you use the console, there's probably little reason to use DataReceived.

Comment: SO is taking nominations for moderator.  If you have the time I think you would be a good moderator.

Comment: Currently, we have so much data coming into the stream, that we are unsure as to the reliability of the DataReceived event. We are having problems with message parts getting mixed up with each other. I'm guessing it has something to do with the asynchronous part accessing the same shared variable. The buffer is getting modified, I think, not in the order that the data is coming in. Any suggestions? THANK YOU

Comment: Sure, DataReceived runs on another thread.  There's no synchronization visible at all in your snippet so high odds you do have a problem.

Comment: I went ahead and edited method 2 to show more detail, can I add flow control using this method? Thanks

Comment: Nothing you added is relevant, thread synchronization is not the same thing as flow control.  I recommended using "method 1", I have no idea why you are not following the advice.  Over and out.

Comment: Well, Adam seems to think your "desert" is something you should "NEVER" do. More importantly, it is hard to follow advice when I don't know much about thread synchronization or flow control whatsoever, this site is for the curious is it not?

Comment: That is not what I said. I said you shouldn't try to read from the serial port in the DataReceived event and any other event.