# SerialPort DataReceived Event Makes Communication Slower

Tags: c#, .net, windows, event-handling, serial-port

I'm working on a serial port communication application for Windows on .NET 3.5. For legacy purposes, I cannot use any other .NET version.

I need to send some data to some device, wait to see if any data comes within a specific time period. If data comes, I need to process it. If no data comes within the given period, nothing needs to handle.

My first approach to wait for data is timer based:

**[Code 1]**

```
using (System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(nDefaultWait))
{
    bool timeout = false;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => { timeout = true; };
    int nTotalRead = 0;

    do
    {
        timeout = false;
        timer.Start();
        while (!timeout && sp.BytesToRead + nTotalRead < nExpectedBytes)
            ;
        timer.Stop();

        if (sp.BytesToRead == 0)
        {
            // No data received for a time period, consider timed out
            break;
        }

        byte[] inBuffer = ReadSerialPort(sp);
        receivedBytes.AddRange(inBuffer);
        nTotalRead += inBuffer.Length;

    } while (receivedBytes.Count < nExpectedBytes);
```

As it is very CPU bound, it slows down slow computers. I'm trying to modify the code using DataReceived event handler:

**[Code 2]**

```
nTotalRead = 0;
nExpectedBytes = nExpBytes;

do
{
    allDataRead.Reset(); // allDataRead is a ManualResetEvent which is Set from DateReceived event
    allDataRead.WaitOne(nDefaultWait);

    if (sp.BytesToRead == 0)
    {
        // No data received for a time period, consider timed out
        break;
    }

    byte[] inBuffer = ReadSerialPort(sp);
    receivedBytes.AddRange(inBuffer);
    nTotalRead += inBuffer.Length;

} while (receivedBytes.Count < nExpBytes);
```

And the DataReceived event looks like:

```
private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort.BytesToRead + nTotalRead >= nExpectedBytes)
    {
        allDataRead.Set();
    }
}
```

The same code is used for 2 different devices (say Type A and Type B) to communicate. Both kind of devices follow same protocol. But they have different Windows drivers.

Performance is a mandatory requirement. A set of commands needs to complete execution as quickly as possible. Both Code 1 and Code 2 performs almost identically for Type A devices. But, To my surprise for Type B devices, Code 2 is 100x-150x times slower (50 ms vs 7500 ms). Not only that, for Type B devices, the performance of Code 2 to isn't consistent. Sometimes it completes in 3000 ms (where Code 1 completes in 50 ms consistently), some other time it completes in 10000 ms or anywhere in between.

What could possibly be the reason behind this?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for `ReadSerialPort`:

```
private byte[] ReadSerialPort(SerialPort sp)
{
    byte[] inBuffer = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
    sp.Read(inBuffer, 0, inBuffer.Length);
    return inBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Your devices uses different default baud rate values. Baud rate is [detected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.baudrate(v=vs.110).aspx) using device driver. I suggest changing baud rate to a higher value. Note that your device may not support higher baud rates.

Comment: @raidensan: All devices honor 9600 baud rate as specified by the protocol. Even if they have different default baud rate, why Code 1's performance is same for both kind of devices?

Comment: Can you show us the code for `ReadSerialPort(sp)`? If you are using `ReadExisting()` or `ReadLine()` in this method, performance will drop in **[Code 2]**, because both these methods block UI. Whereas `DataReceived` runs on a thread. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21689420/2928544). It is a better approach to use `DataReceived` in your case.

Comment: @raidensan: No, I'm using `Read`.

Comment: You'll have to find a site where psychics give out free advice.  Just fix your original code, use Thread.Sleep(1) in the while loop so it doesn't burn 100% core.

Comment: Revise **[Code 2]** to just have `DataReceived` and comment out `ReadSerialPort()` and have only one method of reading data active (either Read() or DataReceived event). It seems that Read method can block other operations ([ref.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Dear @HansPassant, could you explain why `Thread.Sleep(1);` will prevent %100 burn? And why original code is using %100 core? I'd like to learn more on the subject.

Comment: @raidensan: Note that `DataReceived` event isn't reading from serial port. Also, `ReadSerialPort` exists in **Code 1**. I believe there is something else slowing down **Code 2** for Type B devices.